# Are HEIC/HEIF Files Supported In Safari

Tags: safari, ios11, heif

Trying to figure out if Safari does or doesn't support iOS 11's new image format HEIC/HEIF. Have tried numerous things and it doesn't appear to work. Thanks.

Comment: Also curious about support on macOS

Comment: Still does not work in either Safari 13 or Chrome 78.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

By checking on [CanIUse](https://caniuse.com/#search=heif), iOS11 dose't support HEIF in Safari, and I just have a test on iOS11.0.3, yep, it is really not supported.
On MacOS, it is supported on specified platform, which seems like KabyLake CPU, you can check it on WWDC.

Comment: Thanks. Should of thought to check caniuse :)

Comment: Update March 29, 2021 - still no Safari support!  (Per CanIUse.)  Seems a little crazy since it is Apple's proprietary format.

Answer (score -1):

Apple said macOS High Sierra will support the HEIF, you can try it.

Comment: As I said in my question I did try it. It does appear to be supported currently.

Comment: I think you mean "doesn't appear to be supported currently"

Comment: Yes sorry should of been it doesn't appear to be supported currently